# Clojure idioms: sanely pass function-value pairs

Tags: clojure

Sometimes I want to pass argument-value pairs to a higher-order function, where the value I should pass is determined by the argument I pass. I want to be able to pass the argument without explicitly specifying the accompanying value. In particular, I'm interested in the case where the argument is itself a function.

**Generic Example:**

Here's a very generic example, where `my-foo` and `my-bar` are functions that I'm passing to `higher-foo`:

```
(higher-foo my-foo :option4 args) ;good
(higher-foo my-bar :option13 args) ;good
(higher-foo my-foo :option13 args) ;how stupid are you?! my-foo requires :option4!
```

**Question:** Is there a "standard" method for making `:option4` or `:option13` to be inferable by `higher-foo` so that I can just write `(higher-foo my-foo)` and `(higher-foo my-bar)`?

**More Specific Example:**

Bear in mind that there are [better alternatives to the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22766975/2472391), but I'm just trying to put forward a concrete example of what I'm talking about:

```
(defn seq-has? [f n someseq]
    (every? (partial apply f)
            (partition n 1 someseq)))

(defn monotonicity [a b]
    (<= a b))

(defn generalized-fib [a b c]
    (= c (+ a b)))
```

`(seq-has? monotonicity 2 someseq)` should return true if the sequence is monotonic, false otherwise. `(seq-has? generalized-fib 3 someseq)` should return true if the sequence follows the generalized Fibonacci form, false otherwise.

But the "2" and "3" bother me. I could have an arbitrary number of properties to test for, and I don't want to have to remember the appropriate "magic numbers" for such calls.

Note: I know of two ways to do this, and for my own personal use, I suppose they both work. But I'm interested in what is idiomatic or considered best practice in the community. I'll post my answers, but I'm hoping there are more solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are asking for a *standard way* how a function determines a not passed argument from one argument:

```
(defn f 
  ([arg0] (case a :foo (f a :bar) 
                  :baz (f a :quux)))
  ([arg0 arg1] ...))
```

Depending on your use case a different dispatch construct than `case` may be a better fit.

For your generic example this implies that `higher-foo` should determine the correct `:option` in the desired overload like demonstrated above.

In your specific example, you can't determine the `n` from the passed function. You need a more specific datastructure:

```
(defn seq-has? [{:keys [f n]} s]
  (every? (partial apply f)
          (partition n 1 s)))

(def monotonicity
  {:f <=
   :n 2})

(def generalized-fib
  {:f #(= (+ %1 %2) %3)
   :n 3})

(seq-has? monotonicity [1 2 3])
;; => true
```

Answer (score 4):

Just make the predicate function itself take variadic arguments, and have it do the partitioning / recurring. Your monotonic? for instance already exists in core, and is called `<=`

```
(<= 1 2 4 5)
=> true
(<= 1 2 1 5)
=> false
```

Here's the source for the 1, 2 and variadic arg versions:

```
(source <=)
(defn <=
  "Returns non-nil if nums are in monotonically non-decreasing order,
  otherwise false."
  {:inline (fn [x y] `(. clojure.lang.Numbers (lte ~x ~y)))
   :inline-arities #{2}
   :added "1.0"}
  ([x] true)
  ([x y] (. clojure.lang.Numbers (lte x y)))
  ([x y & more]
   (if (<= x y)
     (if (next more)
       (recur y (first more) (next more))
       (<= y (first more)))
     false)))
```

You can make a fib? work the same way, have it take variadic arguments and recur over triples:

```
(defn fib?
  [a b & [c & r]]
  (if (= c (+ a b))
    (if r
      (recur b c r)
      true)
    false))

(fib? 0 1 1)
=> true

(fib? 2 3 5 8 13)
=> true
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Sometimes I overcomplicate things and need another perspective.

Comment: I might not have had that perspective either if I didn't know the variadic arg behavior of less than. You could of course always use your seq-has? as a generalized function inside your preds.

Comment: So, actually, I was a bit tired when I read this the first time. I think your answer is perfect to the question I asked the day before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22740397/2472391). I'm not sure it answers the general problem of function/value pairs, where the value could be anything at all, so long as the "correct" one is determined solely by the function.

Comment: Copied answer to your other linked question.

Answer (score -1):

This solution seems like a hack to me. Is it considered common/idiomatic? Use meta-data on the functions that define the property you are looking for:

```
(defn higher-foo [foo & args]
    (apply foo (:option (meta foo))
               args))

(def my-foo
    (with-meta
        (fn [a b] (println "I'm doing something cool"))
        {:option :option4}))

;using it:
user=> (higher-foo my-foo arg)
```

Comment: Trying to read and use the number of arguments of a function used by a HoF isn't idiomatic and very error-prone.Hackish seems an apt description. I don't see the use of this pattern over variadic argument functions. The only advantage would be to compose functions used by the HoF to reduce the number of traversals of a collection. Theoretically you'd only be able to compose functions with the same arity, but practically you wouldn't be able to deduce the argument count of the resulting composed function.

Comment: Yep. Maybe I should just delete that third method...it may be more distracting than anything else.

Comment: You can't have a variadic overload in a protocol method

Comment: And this entire approach (intended by OP) is nonsense. If two arguments are always tied together the only sane simplification is to make them one argument and change the function that is invoked. Everything else is preposterous. Also writing information on how the function should be invoked into metadata makes no sense. You are just creating a hidden datastructure and have won nothing (e. g. the function can't be invoked with all functions anyway, the hidden datastructure is required).

Comment: The 2 arguments are *not always* tied together. They only occur together when using `higher-foo`. Suppose I have 50 functions that test whether a particular relationship holds between 2-20 numbers (depending on the function). Suppose that these are part of a closed-source library I can't touch. Now suppose I want to test whether or not these relationships hold throughout an ordered collection. NielsK gave a great solution for how to do that by wrapping the 50 functions. What I want to know is, is there a way that doesn't involve writing 50 (or 19) new functions?

Comment: Another example might be functions that sample various statistical distributions. It might be nice if the functions had metadata attached (or something!) so that another programmer could tell whether the functions represented continuous distributions or discrete, and what is their range. Not because you have to know that information in order to use the functions, but because the information might make life easier for other programmers using your code.

Comment: I meant it so: They are always tied together when applied to `higher-foo` and then it makes no sense that `higher-foo` takes them as two different arguments. Regarding helpful metadata with useful information making life easier: You can add a docstring to the functions metadata. Usually it's done via `defn`after the function name.